# FTPing inside of a ksh script, get part not working

Tags: windows, ftp, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
. $HOME/bin/init.ksh
log_start
exit_if_not_dgftp

EXPIRE_DAYS=30

create_arc_dir
handle_error abort $? "Command create_arc_dir failed" $USER

purge_archive $EXPIRE_DAYS

WORK_FILE=RetriesExceeded.csv
USER=LawsonIT-FinMM@test.org
HOST=lawsonfax.test.org

# Ftp the file
# Ftp username and password is in .netrc

$FTP -v $HOST
lcd $WORK_FILE
get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit

archive_file $WORK_FILE

# /law/bin/mpack -s "Fax Retries Exceeded" $WORK_FILE_OUTPUT $USER

log_stop
exit 0
```

ERROR:
Not recognizing the 'get' portion of the script and down.  It is working throught he connection.

```
[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$ get_lawson_fax.ksh
Connected to lawsonfax.test.org.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for dgftp.
230 User logged in.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[33]: lcd:  not found
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[34]: get:  not found
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[35]: quit:  not found
[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$
```

The file I'm getting is on a windows server.

Comment: You are not actually passing the ftp commands to the ftp session (so your shell is trying to interpret them) - you probably should be using a *here document* as shown here [How to use ftp in a shell script](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html)

Comment: I'm sorry not quite sure how to do that.  That does make sense what you're saying, but not sure how to code that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a *here document* to pass commands to the ftp session's standard input:

```
$FTP -v "$HOST" << EOF
lcd "$WORK_FILE"
get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit
EOF
```

The `EOF` string can be replaced by any arbitrary word to denote the start and end of input.